# xpath find all attributes with specific name under specific root

Tags: xpath

In order to find all attributes with name `myAttr` in the document I can do this `//@myAttr` but what if I want to specify the root and still find all attributes with that name in the document? Something like `/root/{whatever_or_nothing}/@myAttribute`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this way :

```
/root//@myAttribute
```